# Lazy loading with the MySQL connector

Tags: c#, mysql, lazy-loading

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 project using MySql 5.1.53 and MySql Connector/Net 6.4.4 on Windows 7 x64. In my application, I query the my database as:

```
IQueryable<Zoo> my_query = from d in my_context_.MySet
                                  .Include("Foo")
                                  .Include("Bar")
                                  where d.Fuzz.Status == (int)Status.Pending
                                  orderby d.Order
                                  select d;

foreach (Zoo z in my_query)
{
    if (some_expression)
    {
        // Lazy load some more data from the query. This throws a 
        // MySqlException
        z.Something.Load();
    }
    else
    {
        // Lazy load some other data from the query. This also throws a 
        // MySqlException
        z.SomethingElse.Load();
    }
}
```

The exception I get is:

```
System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

I would really prefer to be able to lazy-load the rest of my object as its elements are needed. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to .Include() my entire object in the original query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error you're getting, you appear to still have the connection open that is being used to load in data from the initial query, so you can't open another connection on the same context.

Try materializing your query first, so you are not trying to lazy load while you are still loading the initial batch of data in:

```
var list = my_query.ToList();
foreach (Zoo z in list)
...
```

Comment: I can do that, but won't that cause a problem if the query returns a gazillion results and it takes longer than the sql timeout to return that much data all at once?

Comment: @PaulH: This should actually reduce your likelihood of getting a timeout, since you won't be attempting to perform additional round-trips to the database while the data from the initial request is coming across the wire.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I downvoted your answer because it's a workaround, not a real solution, imo.  Your solution forces an extra enumeration of the list, not to mention it reveals how leaky this abstraction is (the developer shouldn't have to know to force enumeration because the underlying provider doesn't fully support multiple data readers).  Other providers (e.g., Devart dotconnect) handle this appropriately, and the ToList() is not required.

Comment: @manu08: I totally understand your frustration with the framework. If you find a better solution for the problem given, that's fantastic: please share it. Regardless, I would encourage you to follow the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. Namely: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support multiple active result sets (MARS) like SQL Server.  I don't think EFs implementation of your query is going to allow this.

However, you could make a Lazy generic of type Task that has a factory action that executes the LINQ query to EF.

Comment: Do I need to .Include() every part of my object for this query separately or is there a way to temporarily disable lazy loading or .IncludeAll()?

Comment: If you execute one of the resolving LINQ statements like ToList() or Single() in the factory method of the Lazy, you'll be resolving the IQueryable completely.

Comment: Are you suggesting the same solution as @StriplingWarrior? I'm concerned that if the IQueryable returns too many results and I try to read them all at once I could get a timeout exception.

Comment: If you're going to use them all, I think you're safe fetching them.  How much data are we talking about?  Your query should use enough filters to limit your data set before calling ToList or Single.  I was saying keep your Lazy benefit by using the generic Lazy class and put your LINQ query in the factory action

Comment: What is a generic Lazy class? Is there an example of this online you can point to?

Comment: This isn't a MySQL limitation, it's a connector limitation.  I'm still looking into the nuts and bolts, but Devart's MySQL connector supports proper lazy-loading.  I'm still trying to get it to work with the MySQL Community Connector.